# aui: tag write using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

please how can I write aui:input HTML code via document.write() JavaScript function?

example:

```
document.write('<aui:input name="' + name + '" label="' + name + '" type="text" />');
```

same problem with:

```
document.write('<aui:input name="' + name + '" label="' + name + '" type="text"> </aui:input>');
```

I can only write standard  tag.

Thank you :) .

edit (reaction on a  Lucas NN's comment):

if I try to use aui:input instead of input it crashes with this error:

`00:47:21,317 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 8: 23: unterminated string literal
00:47:21,318 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 8: 23: syntax error
00:47:21,319 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 85: 12: missing ; before statement
00:47:21,319 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 89: 14: missing ; before statement
00:47:21,320 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 100: 5: illegally formed XML syntax
00:47:21,320 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 100: 5: syntax error
00:47:21,321 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 120: 17: missing ; before statement
00:47:21,321 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 134: 9: unterminated regular expression literal
00:47:21,322 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 138: 7: unterminated regular expression literal
00:47:21,322 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 141: 3: unterminated string literal
00:47:21,323 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-65][MinifierUtil:111] 1: 0: Compilation produced 10 syntax errors.`

Comment: What is your real question? document.write() is used like in your examples, no secrets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second piece of code is ok just remove the `aui:` in your input tags. Same with your first piece. The reason we remove aui it is part of a different javascript library and it will not work with pure/no-library javascript. Plus, if my source is correct, aui was replaced with the YUI Library.

I would not know if you had another js library if you did not add the src.
What I mean is, aui is a different library, You need to have the script src defined.

If you used the aui/YUI compiler, None of this will help

http://alloyui.com/tutorials/form-builder/ 
Also, Take a look at the form syntax with YUI/AUI it's a different approach, but it works.